# Upload Blob Azure DefaultAzureCredential Input does not contain any JSON tokens

Tags: c#, string, azure-web-app-service, defaultazurecredential

I am trying to follow the Upload to Blob tutorial from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal - and want to use Managed Identity instead of the access key as that gets rotated and have added the Role Assignment from my App Service.

In my local - I test spinning up a BlobContainerClient with the client ID as such

```
string userAssignedClientId = ""; //Use Object/Principal ID from App Service - Webapps here
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });
```

When I try to use the client

```
await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

I get the error

```
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Managed Identity response was not in the expected format. Input does not contain any JSON tokens
```

I have checked the role and it seems to have Storage Blob Contributor - am I missing something here or given this is a Microsoft tutorial - and not much research is this a new feature that is still buggy?

I have also tried

```
services.Configure<AzureStorageConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConfig"));
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

where my AppConfig has the details but I am confused on the Azure directory details.  I thought you were able to only use your ObjectID/Principal ID in your Identity activated webapp per the instructions so I only entered in the ClientID - is that correct or will I actually need all the details including secret?

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "ClientId": "Principal/Object Web App ID",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    // the following is required to handle Continuous Access Evaluation challenges
    "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "AzureStorageConfig": {
    "AccountName": "<storage-account-name>",
    "ContainerName": "<blob-container-name>"

  },
```